# Convergent sequnces in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{\vec{u_k}\}$ be a sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\vec{u}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the sequence $\{\vec{u_k}\}$ converges to $\vec{u}$ if and only if
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle \vec{u_k},\vec{v} \rangle = \langle \vec{u},\vec{v} \rangle.$$

Attempted Solution:Suppose $\{\vec{u_k}\}$ converges to $\vec{u}$. Then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \vec{u_k}-\vec{u} = \vec{0} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle \vec{u_k},\vec{v} \rangle-\langle \vec{u},\vec{v}\rangle = \lim_{k\to\infty}\langle\vec{u_k}-\vec{u},\vec{v}\rangle = \langle \vec{0},\vec{v}\rangle = 0\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle \vec{u_k},\vec{v}\rangle = \langle \vec{u},\vec{v}\rangle$. I am having a really hard time figuring out how to best argue to converse. I feel like using componentwise convergense may be best but I am still unsure how to impliment the idea in the proof.

Comment: Do you know why $\;\lim\langle \vec{u_k}-\vec u,\vec v\rangle=\langle 0,\vec v\rangle\;$ ? This is not obvious: depends on the inner product being a continuous fucntion.

Comment: This looks like a job for the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said in a comment, your proof is valid only if you know that the standard inner product is a continuous mapping. I also think that you mean that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle\vec{u}_k,\vec{v}\rangle =\langle \vec{u},\vec{v}\rangle
$$
For every $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (otherwise, you could take any sequence and let $\vec{v}=0$). If this is the case, as hint you can take $\vec{v}=\vec{e}_i$ where $\{\vec{e}_1, \ldots, \vec{e}_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and apply your hypothesis $n$ times.
In either case, I think it's convenient to remember that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\vec{u}_k=\vec{u}$ if and only if 
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\vec{u}_k)_i=(\vec{u})_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ where $(\vec{u})_i$ is the $i$-th entry of the vector $\vec{u}$.